# Using refile gem to upload a photo in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, refile

Currently, I am using refile for my users to upload photos in their profile. I am trying to be able to add photos to their profile for them through active admin. For some reason, I can't get it to work. Does anyone have an example of working code? This is where I am at.

This is what I have in my user.rb file in active admin

```
f.inputs "Images Files" do
        f.has_many :images do |item|
            # item.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.attachment_field :images_files, multiple: true, presigned: true, direct: true
            item.file_field :images_files, multiple: true, presigned: true, direct: true
        end
    end 

permit_params images: [:created_at, :updated_at, :ambassador_id, :file_id]
```